# Speakers not showing up, default audio device is headphones

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and the default audio device is headphones and my speakers (built-in) are not showing up in sound settings. What's more that the headphone jack of my HP Probook 6550b laptop is broken so I can't test if I am getting audio output or not. How do I setup my speakers? Please guide me properly as I am a beginner in terms of Linux and terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved on the Linux Questions forum, so if anyone has this problem, check this link out:  [[SOLVED] Speakers not working, Default audio device is headphone](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/speakers-not-working-default-audio-device-is-headphone-4175673286/)

> After updating the `alsa-base.conf` with options `snd-hda-intel model=auto probe_mask=1` I rebooted the pc and opened `pavucontrol`.
> The default audio device was headphones again but I switched to
> speakers which it was showing unavailable SS. After that I played some
> audio and it was working. I think its a bug because of which it is
> showing my speakers unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is common among Ubuntu variations, but are easily resolved. At some point, there will be a fix to this issue; but until then, here is mine.

After many tries, I happened upon the following simple solution:

1. Open a terminal,
2. Type, 'alsamixer' and press the Enter key.
3. You will see the alsa mixer as output in your terminal.
4. Select your correct sound card by pressing F6. I just used the down arrow to get to the sound card.
5. Use the left right arrow keys to land on each volume control; and the up down arrow keys to change its volume level.
6. If “MM” appears below the vertical volume bar, then that control is muted. Press, 'm' key to undo it. The new Volume is now set to 00. You can now, increase the volume using up down keys.

**MOST IMPORTANT:** Inspect **every** volume control, all the way to the right-most. In my case, **AUTO-MUTE** on startup, was enabled. Disabling it, fixed my volume problem. Sound, returned.

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Start by resetting your audio setting with

```
pulseaudio --kill
```